# Unknown App when confirming in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, newsstand-kit

I have created a newsstand app and have everything working. The only issues I have now are:

When I click 'subscribe' and the dialogue box pops up to confirm the in app purchase it says

```
Confirm Subscription
Do you want subscribe to Unknown App for free?
[Environment: Sandbox]
```

Why does it say `Unknown App`? Everything else works (receipt validation, completing the transaction & co.)

Also, will the `[Environment: Sandbox]` go away automatically once I upload it to the app store and download it for real? Is there something in my code that I am missing that sends the in app purchase request to the sandbox? Or is it just because i am using a test device that has the app compiled onto it from XCode.

Comment: did the name came properly in production?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your app is not in app store, it shows you the [Environment: Sandbox]. It will automatically go away once you uploaded app and your app is in app store.

**For "Unknown App":**

You need to add text in inApp purchase section in iTunes connect. If you haven't done that it will show you "Unknown App" on message which comes on iOS pop-up.When you activate in-app purchase by filling all information in inApp purchase section, pop-up will not show you "Unknown App", rather the pop-up will mention your app name.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Both the sandbox and 'Unknown App' went away once the app went live.

Comment: In my case, 'Unknown App' reflect the rejected state of my in app purchase on iTunes Connect. You will get 'Unknown App' for SkProduct item's localized name but, with a correct price. They went away when my app got approved.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is not in app store, it shows you the [Environment: Sandbox]. it will automatically will go away once you uploaded and your app is in app store.

Comment: thanks! what about the 'Unknown App' text in the subscribe box?

Comment: I think you need to check your app name or the information that you filled while enabling the in-app purchase. you haven't filled some field which is causing unknown app. i worked on it long back but i think we need to give some message for in-app purchase. you should check all these things.Even check the id that you have provided to app.

Comment: did the name came properly in production?

Comment: the name did come in production. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your binary has been rejected by Apple, the IAP products submitted with it should also show up as rejected.  When you try and purchase a rejected IAP within the app, the confirmation screen will show the aforementioned "Do you want to buy one Unknown App...".

To correct this you should be able to make a small change to each IAP product in iTunes Connect. Then simply change it back, then the `rejected` flag should go away (and be replaced by `waiting for review`. For example, I added an 's' to the `Display Name` for the English language of each product. Then went right back in and removed the 's'.

This may not be acceptable to Apple if the reason for your rejection centers around your use of In-App Purchases.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check your **itunesconnect account**.

Goto your Specific App "NewStandApp" .-> Manage InAppPurchases. Now check Reference Name you have Added with your ProductID.

Product_Id your are referring in project/app (sandbox environment) might be connected with app name  "Unknown app"